# Validation Error django not working in my template

Tags: python, django

In my register form I added a validation error when there is a duplicate username or email, but it is not working in my template.

forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username is not unique")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not unique")
        return email
```

the template:

```
   <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username</label><br>
        {{forms.username}} <br>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        {{forms.email}} <br>
        <label for="password1">Password</label><br>
        {{forms.password1}} <br>
        <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label><br>
        {{forms.password2}} <br>

        {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                {{ error|escape }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %} <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegisterForm
# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    
    context = {'forms':form}
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', context)
```

When I run the page and put a duplicate email then no validation error is raised, it just reloads the page removing the email or the username.

Comment: Can we see your views.py file.

Comment: your Form is passed in context as forms and not form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "register view" you set context:

```
context = {'forms':form}
```

But in the template, you use "form.errors":

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error|escape }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %} <br><br>
```

You must change "form.errors" to "forms.errors" in the template.